# Sub Array dentro un Array usando ng-repeat AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, array, arraylist, ng-repeat

tengo dos tablas las cuales estan realcionadas  por un IdEntidad la cual quiero mostrarlo agrupado ***EN UNA TABLA***

Eh estado haciendo de esta manera:

```
var app = angular.module("RodoApp", []);
app.controller("RodoController", function ($scope, $http) {

    $http.get('/Usuario/GetEntidad').then(function (response) {
        $scope.EntidadList = response.data;
    });

    $http.get('/Usuario/GetUnindad').then(function (response) {
        $scope.UnidadList = response.data;
    });
});
```

tengo dos tablas

ENTIDAD

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

UNIDAD

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

las cuales quiero mostrar de esta manera dentro una tabla

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Tu pregunta no esta clara. Quieres mostrar los resultados en un `select` o en una tabla?

Comment: @Einer quiero mostrar todo esto en una tabla

Answer (score 1):

Lo que puedes hacer es crear una variable nueva llamada `$scope.newItems = [ ];` donde vas almacenar los nuevos `items` que vas a filtrar y hacer uso del método **filter()** como puedes observar continuación, quedo atento ante cualquier inquietud.

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $http) {

    $scope.newItems = [];

    $scope.EntidadList  = [
      {
        "idEntidad": 1,
        "Nombre": "Ecuador"
      },
      {
        "idEntidad": 2,
        "Nombre": "Bolivia"
      },
      {
        "idEntidad": 3,
        "Nombre": "Peru"
      }
    ];

    $scope.UnidadList = [
      {
        "idUnidad": 1,
        "idIdentidad": 1,
        "Nombre": "Quito"
      },
      {
        "idUnidad": 2,
        "idIdentidad": 1,
        "Nombre": "Guayaquil"
      },
      {
        "idUnidad": 3,
        "idIdentidad": 2,
        "Nombre": "Cochabamba"
      },
      {
        "idUnidad": 4,
        "idIdentidad": 2,
        "Nombre": "La paz"
      },
      {
        "idUnidad": 5,
        "idIdentidad": 3,
        "Nombre": "Cusco"
      }
    ];

    $scope.mostrarItems= function() {
        for (var i = 0; i < $scope.EntidadList.length; i++) {
            $scope.UnidadList.filter( (o) => { 
                if (o.idIdentidad == $scope.EntidadList[i].idEntidad) {
                    o.Pais = $scope.EntidadList[i].Nombre;
                    $scope.newItems.push(o);
                }
            });
        }
    }    
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

    <div class="container">
        <table class="table" ng-init="mostrarItems()">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="col">Pais</th>
                    <th scope="col">Nombre</th>
                    <th scope="col">Id Identitad</th>
                    <th scope="col">Id Unidad</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="item in newItems">
                <td scope="row" ng-bind="item.Pais"></td>
                <td ng-bind="item.Nombre"></td>
                <td ng-bind="item.idIdentidad"></td>
                <td ng-bind="item.idUnidad"></td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Otra solución posible seria de la siguiente manera como tu quieres agrupar las ciudades dependiendo del país:

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $http) {

    $scope.newArr = [];

    $scope.EntidadList  = [
      {
        "idEntidad": 1,
        "Nombre": "Ecuador"
      },
      {
        "idEntidad": 2,
        "Nombre": "Bolivia"
      },
      {
        "idEntidad": 3,
        "Nombre": "Peru"
      }
    ];

    $scope.UnidadList = [
      {
        "idUnidad": 1,
        "idIdentidad": 1,
        "Nombre": "Quito"
      },
      {
        "idUnidad": 2,
        "idIdentidad": 1,
        "Nombre": "Guayaquil"
      },
      {
        "idUnidad": 3,
        "idIdentidad": 2,
        "Nombre": "Cochabamba"
      },
      {
        "idUnidad": 4,
        "idIdentidad": 2,
        "Nombre": "La paz"
      },
      {
        "idUnidad": 5,
        "idIdentidad": 3,
        "Nombre": "Cusco"
      }

    ];

    $scope.newArrayItem = function() {
        for (var i = 0; i < $scope.EntidadList.length; i++) {
            var filterCiudades = $scope.UnidadList.filter(function(o) {
                return o.idIdentidad == $scope.EntidadList[i].idEntidad;
            });
            $scope.EntidadList[i].ciudades = filterCiudades;
        }
        $scope.newArr = $scope.EntidadList;
    }    
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

    <div class="container">
        <table class="table" ng-init="newArrayItem()">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="col">Pais</th>
                    <th scope="col">Ciudades del Pais</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="item in newArr">
                <td scope="row" ng-bind="item.Nombre"></td>
                <td ng-repeat="ciudad in item.ciudades" ng-bind="ciudad.Nombre"></td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```